# Extract data from table based on a month- How to?

Tags: matlab

I have a table, I want to know how to have only January data from all years (only January from all years (1989-2018))?
I tried this:

```
mytable_Jan = mytable(mytable.date == "Jan", :);
```

But not working, the error is:

> Unable to convert the text 'Jan' to a datetime value because its
>   format was not recognized.

[The table is attached](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1edWVUloZA3_SzJAbxneKB5M2-QFHZcJL)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is to use `month(mytable.date)`:

```
mytable_Jan = mytable(month(mytable.date) == 1, :)
```